# SQL Merge - Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server

I have an OUTPUT clause on a SQL merge that I've identified as the cause of this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

I am outputting to a temp table with a single field, and I'm flummoxed as to why I'm getting this error.

```
CREATE TABLE #PermissionChanges(
    ChangeType NVARCHAR(10)
)

MERGE INTO [dbo].[PermissionClient] AS Target
        USING (VALUES (@permissionId, @clientId, 1))
            AS Source ([PermissionId], [ClientId], [Enabled])   
        ON (Target.[ClientId] = @clientId AND Target.[PermissionId] = Source.[PermissionId])
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET [Enabled] = Source.[Enabled]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT ([PermissionId], [ClientId], [Enabled])
            VALUES (@permissionId, @clientId , Source.[Enabled])
        OUTPUT
             $ACTION ChangeType 
             INTO #PermissionChanges;
```

If I change the OUTPUT to this:

```
  OUTPUT $ACTION;
```

the script executes successfully and I get:

```
$ACTION
-------
UPDATE
```

Comment: can you try with: OUTPUT $ACTION INTO #PermissionChanges; (so get rid of ChangeType) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that specifying the column name which I wanted to `OUTPUT` the `$Action` into solved the issue, something I also saw in *some* of the [MERGE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-inserting-the-results-of-the-merge-statement-into-another-table).

```
OUTPUT $ACTION ChangeType INTO #PermissionChanges(ChangeType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your existing table structure as the following code:

```
USE tempdb
GO

-- Clean up
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#PermissionChanges','u') is not null
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #results
END

CREATE TABLE #PermissionChanges(
    ChangeType NVARCHAR(10)
)
GO


-- Clean up
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.[dbo].[PermissionClient]','u') is not null
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #results
END

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PermissionClient]
([PermissionId] int
, [ClientId] int
, [Enabled] int
)
GO

DECLARE @clientId int
SET @clientId=1
DECLARE @permissionId int
SET @permissionId=1


MERGE INTO [dbo].[PermissionClient] AS Target
        USING (VALUES (@permissionId, @clientId, 1))
            AS Source ([PermissionId], [ClientId], [Enabled])   
        ON (Target.[ClientId] = @clientId AND Target.[PermissionId] = Source.[PermissionId])
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET [Enabled] = Source.[Enabled]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT ([PermissionId], [ClientId], [Enabled])
            VALUES (@permissionId, @clientId , Source.[Enabled])
        OUTPUT
             $ACTION ChangeType 
             INTO #PermissionChanges;

SELECT * FROM #PermissionChanges
```

returns

```
ChangeType
INSERT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ChangeType from the OUTPUT clause:

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[PermissionClient] AS Target
    USING (VALUES (@permissionId, @clientId, 1))
        AS Source ([PermissionId], [ClientId], [Enabled])   
    ON (Target.[ClientId] = @clientId AND Target.[PermissionId] = Source.[PermissionId])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET [Enabled] = Source.[Enabled]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ([PermissionId], [ClientId], [Enabled])
        VALUES (@permissionId, @clientId , Source.[Enabled])
    OUTPUT
         $ACTION 
         INTO #PermissionChanges;
```